# Mega Run time issue (brute-force approach) , Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am trying to make a schedule out of facts, facts are in form of course_meetings(subject,type,group,description),

I decided to use the brute-force approach

I will generate all possible schedules and see which one will pass all the constraints,
however the the facts I have generate 2.6, how can I optimize that, and is there a better approach.
for ex.
course_meetings(subject,type,group,instructor,description).
solve:-

```
findall([A,B,C,D,E],course_meetings(A,B,C,D,E),L),
permutation(L,L1),
%and apply constrains on it.
```

i have 32 facts of this format and for permutation its 32!~= 2.6*10^32

Comment: I came across something called assert/retract , is it useful and if so how can i.

Comment: show us example of your specification. What are the contraints that you must keep? Also, if this is a homework or a test, please say so or tag your post accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constraints over finite domains have been designed in Prolog to fit exactly this need. No need to use assert/rectract for that. See e.g. [library(clpfd)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html). To get you acquainted, you might look at [this example, a "Simplistic School Time-Tabler"](https://www.metalevel.at/simsttab/) and the [CLP Primer](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/clpfd)

Comment: I will try it and let u know, am currently looking at the time-table

Answer (score 2):

Trying all possible permutations does not seem to be a good idea. An alternative might be to express your constraint as finite-domain constraints of clp(fd) and let the constraint solver to try a better strategy than "try everything".